# Es posible Omitir Variables en la URL al momento de evaluarlas?

Tags: php

Quiero evaluar la url  y según lo que contenga hacer diferentes acciones( todas la url escritas  se redireccionan al index )

pero eh llegado a un problema  con variables es decir

una url nomal seria  por ejemplo

```
http://localhost/myapp/productos
```

y una con  Variable podria ser

```
http://localhost/myapp/productos/find/2
```

Envió el url para luego responder con un json

El código que tengo hasta ahora

```
$var = $_GET['url'];
switch ($var) {
case "productos":
 echo "i es igual a 0";
 break;
 //Aqui esta el problema no se como decirle a php que omita el numero que escriba el usuario
            case "productos/find/":
                echo "i es igual a 1";
                break;
            case 2:
                echo "i es igual a 2";
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno al final resovi el  problema con este codigo

```html
        $var = $_GET['url']; 
        $numero = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $var), 10); 

        switch ($var) {
            case "productos":
                echo "todos los productos";
                break;
            case "productos/find/$numero":
                echo "find";
                break;
            case "productos/familia/$numero":
                echo "i es igual a 2";
                break;
        }
```

Lo que hace es que saca extrae cualquier numero de 10 dígitos de un string  y luego al comparar solo le agrego la variable en la cual esta el numero que extraje

Answer (score 1):

Puedes declarar lo siguiente:

```
$var = $_GET['url'];
$partes = explode('/', $var);
$to_remove = array_pop($partes);
$sin_id = implode('/', $to_remove);
$comparar = (preg_match('/^\d+$/', $to_remove) !== false) ? $sin_id : $var;
//Ahora puedes hacer tu switch como kerias pero en vez de usar $var, usas $comparar
```

En fin lo que hice fue separar en partes tu url y eliminar el ultimo elemento y asignar a la variable comparar url si no pasas un numero al final de la url y sino le asigno la variable sin_id que es la url formateada sin el número.